# Does each node dynamically connects to its connected nodes' peers?

Tags: go-ethereum, network, peers, enode

I want to give example from private Ethereum network which has 5 nodes, but we can generalize it for much larger network that has thousands of nodes. On the figure double arrows represents connected peers, which they add themselves using `addPeer()`. Later, `Node_1` adds `Node_-2` and `Node-3` as peers using `addPeer()` since it only knows `enode://pubkey@ip:port` of {`Node-2` and `Node-3`} and connects to the network.

[image]

**[Q1]** After that, does `Node_1` automatically fetches `Node-2` and `Node-3`'s connected nodes's `enode://pubkey@ip:port`,  which are {`Node-4` and `Node-5`} and dynamically connects to them? and afterwards also fetches `Node-4` and `Node-5`'s connected nodes's `enode://pubkey@ip:port` which is `Node-6` and connects into that. This operation could be done recursively. If no, does `Node-1` statically remains as only connected to `Node-2` and `Node-3`.

**[Q2]** This one is connected to first question. If `Node-1` cannot fetch the `Node-2` and `Node-3`'s connected nodes's `enode://pubkey@ip:port` and only remain connected to `Node-2` and `Node-3`, after few hours `Node-2` and `Node-3` shuts down. Does it leads `Node-1` disconnects from the network as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, when a new node is added in the blockchain network a mesh network is formed among the nodes. This is the core conceptual idea of **decentralization**. If some node is down then the system can remain up till at least one node in the blockchain network is up.

[image: mesh_network]

According to [geth documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network)-

**How Peers Are Found**

> Geth continuously attempts to connect to other nodes on the network
>   until it has peers. If you have UPnP enabled on your router or run
>   ethereum on an Internet-facing server, it will also accept connections
>   from other nodes.
>
> Geth finds peers through something called the discovery protocol. In
>   the discovery protocol, nodes are gossipping with each other to find
>   out about other nodes on the network. In order to get going initially,
>   geth uses a set of bootstrap nodes whose endpoints are recorded in the
>   source code.

Comment: So if there is 1000 nodes, does newly connected node (only adds a single peer); later does it connects to all 1000 nodes over time? If yes how? @asvisosila

Comment: @alper, I have updated my answer.

Comment: How about in `Parity`, does it also do similar approach like `geth` does?

Comment: I don't know about parity but I think conceptual idea will remain same in parity as well